# How do I get the id of the last tweet using twython?

Tags: python, twitter, twython

what I want is to eliminate the last tweet, for that I use the following:

```
    l = len(sys.argv)

if l >= 2:
    twid = sys.argv[1]
else:
    twid = input("ID number of tweet to delete: ")

try:
    tweet = twitter.destroy_status(id=twid)
except TwythonError as e:
    print(e)
```

It runs perfect.

You see I need the "ID" but not how to get it.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: um. As in the twitter ID or the ID in your program? I assume the id is in the URL when you click a tweet - https://twitter.com/cgpgrey/status/752232623968137216 i.e. 752232623968137216 in this case.

Comment: @Tim Yes, this ID. I need to somehow get it and store it in a variable

Comment: Well, select it. Copy it. Paste it. Enter it as input, then it's stored in `twid`.

Comment: But I need it automatic!
I have to run a script (made in python) to delete the last tweet.

Comment: Well how does twython get tweets? Try `twitter.get_home_timeline()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

```
user_timeline=twitter.get_user_timeline(screen_name="BarackObama", count=20)
for tweet in user_timeline:
    print tweet["id"]
```

It prints the 20 lastest tweets id of Barack Obama.

Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_user_timeline with your personal screen name to retrieve the tweet, and then access it with tweet[0] since it will be in the first index.

```
tweet = twitter.get_user_timeline(
            screen_name=YOUR_SCREEN_NAME,
            count=1)
twitter.destroy_status(id=tweet[0]['id'])
```